# what to store image or its path in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and i want to store some images. I read on forum that instead of storing directly images as 'BLOB', store images in directory and there path in database. But what if user will delete any image from directory(or by some other means image gets deleted). Is there any way to handle that situation ? And why its not preferd to store images directly in db?

**EDIT**: The database is not related to website development. I am developing a software in which user will take some images using camera and after playing with it, I want to store a record for that image in database with some other parameters(in which one column is for  storing image). The software and database is going to run on users PC. And I am going to generate (probably in excel) final report of all records.

Comment: Up to you, but 999 times out of 1000, the path is stored. This topic is w-i-d-e-l-y discussed, and the subject of fervent opinion.

Comment: `But what if user will delete any image from directory(or by some other means image gets deleted).` If you want the be shown forever, then you need to save the image to your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while storing image in mysql can lead to increasing size and load for the database. If your site have a high volume, traffic site, this is not a good idea. Instead, i usually prefer to store the image files in a folder & update its path in the database. The main thing you need to take care is setting a unique name (such as img1_2014_04_20_16_30_25.JPG) in order to prevent the file getting overwritten. In the above mentioned name can be made unique using the time functions easily.  Then there is no direct way of handling such error with mysql as far as i know, all you can do with your front end is to make sure the image exist or put a default no image as display.

Comment: Since, you mentioned images from cam (which can vary from 1Mb to several Mbs), i personally wont recommend in storing them to the database. I would rather prefer to save them as a unique named image in some location in the users computer & save the file name into the db. I believe, this can actually improve the performance of your application while fetching the data for the excel.

Comment: Hi, yes now am going to store images in directory and path in database, but the question remains. What if image get deleted or renamed from directory(we should always assume that user is a lay man) outside software

Comment: Yes, We should. In PHP there is a function file_exists() which allows the user to check if the file exists, with which we can know weather the file exist or not. While making the report, check the file availability before you print into that report. That will take care of all the files that exist in the database & system only will be there...

Comment: Thanks, i will try to add that interlock. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can never be 100% sure that the images won't get deleted. Of course for extra security you can give permission only to a certain user to the directory and the files inside. Downside of storing blobs - as much as MySQL is capable of handling quite big databases, images can add up  ridiculous amount of size to the database and it will be much harder to manage, maintain and optimize if it gets really big. Migration will be really difficult if you decide to swap the engine, and even more painful if you decide to go with a noSQL solution(couchdb, mongo, etc.). Perhaps you could set up a cron to iterate through all the records and check if the file exists. If it doesn't, drop the record from the table. Then again I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly. If a user has the option to delete an image, I assume it's going to happen through some interface. You will need to implement a logic so that:

1) The file gets deleted

2) The record is deleted from the database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for useful explanation. There is no option given to user for deleting image, but since software and db is going to run on his pc, there is always a possibility that he can delete or move any image from directory outside software. So i just wanted to handle that situation. Your option of deleting record if file doesn't exist seems good, but it may lost bunch of data if directory is moved or renamed outside my software. And yes setting permissions is one option.